# Location of xterm fonts on Debian 7

Tags: linux, fonts, xterm, debian-wheezy

I'm trying to get xterm working on a cloud server that I've just created. I've installed xterm, when run it I get `xterm: cannot load font '-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1`. I've been researching this for a couple of hours, I've downloaded the [missing font](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs-fonts.html), I'm not sure where to place it though.

Does anyone know which folder xterm is looking in for fonts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the missing font did not resolve this. I resolved it by installing `xfonts-base`, then un & re-installing xterm. That took care of it, now xterm is working.

Comment: FYI, all I had to do was load said `xfonts-base` package, then log out and log back in (restarting X, I presume...)